# mapreduce function while querying in hive

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hive, bigdata

what hive query do. can anyone please explain briefly with example when we query in hive, how the process of mapreduce process the output.

for example, 
1. select * from tablename where/join 
2. partition
3. bucket

please explain how mapreduce internally executes the hive query.

Comment: Order of reading : HDFS -> Map reduce -> problems querying for Data in HDFS -> SQL -> Hive(SQl over data in HDFS using Map reduce) -> Performance in Hive(Partitions and Buckets). Once you answers to the above, you can come back again to ask here. Please help yourself, before asking for help. happy learning

Comment: yes i do know the concepts of HDFS, MR, SQL. i have read o'reilly of Hive but i could not find the detail explanation of how MR does while we query in hive.
to bried my question: i need answer for what select, from tablename, where, partition, bucket done in MR.